# notify_airbrake throws error on custom classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

We use airbrake throughout our codebase which works great except for custom classes that do not inherit from a Rails hierarchy (i.e. ActiveRecord).

Some code:

```
class Offer
  def counter(amount, qty=1)
    begin
      offers_response = viyet_mage_rest_client.counter_offer(@id.to_i, amount, qty.to_i)
    rescue => e
      notify_airbrake(e)
      offers_response = []
    end
  end
end
```

In airbrake we see:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `notify_airbrake' for Offer:Class
```

As the error. I want the actual error and not an error for reporting an error!

Our airbrake.rb file:

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging? 
  Airbrake.configure do |config|
    config.api_key = Settings.airbrake.api_key
    config.secure = true
  end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Try `Airbrake.notify(e)` instead of `notify_airbrake(e)`.

Comment: `notify_airbrake` is for use in controllers only. ref: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/rails/action_controller.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you need is `Airbrake.notify_or_ignore()`. For your given example:

```
class Offer
  def counter(amount, qty=1)
    begin
      offers_response = viyet_mage_rest_client.counter_offer(@id.to_i, amount, qty.to_i)
    rescue => e
      Airbrake.notify_or_ignore(e)
      offers_response = []
    end
  end
end
```

More detail can be found here: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Using-Airbrake-with-plain-Ruby